# Map a dataset to a custom .NET object in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, database, object, datatable, mapping

I want to map data from datatable to custom .NET object. Let's say, I have a .NET object

```
Public Class MyClass
    Public ID
    Public Prop1
    Public Prop2
End Class
```

And a corresponding table in the database, which contains columns ID, Prop1 and Prop2.

I want to generate a list of .NET objects from the database. Currently I fill the dataset and map each property individually. Is there any way, to map the database automatically, so the properties would map according to property / column name.

```
'retreive dataset from db'
DaAdapter.Fill(ds)

'create a new list of my object'
Private l As New List(Of MyClass)

'iterate through dataset (this is the step I want to get rid of - of course'
'it could only work if the property of the MyClass and the column in '
'the database have the same name)'
For Each r As DataRow in ds.Tables(0).Rows
    Dim itm As New MyClass
    itm.ID = r("ID")
    itm.Prop1 = r("Prop1")
    itm.Prop2 = r("Prop2")
    l.Add(itm)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some sort of Object Relational Mapping (ORM) framework. [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723) is one of them

Answer (score 1):

IMHO. The easiest way is using [Linq2Sql](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way , although many tools are available to create classes that exactly resembles database tables called Entity classes. See the following link for more details

[Database tables to C# entity classes - generator for FluentNHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600669/database-tables-to-c-sharp-entity-classes-generator-for-fluentnhibernate)

You can also use typeddataset, codesmith tool.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You can use a `database first` approach where you just point to your database and it will create the Entities and associations for you.

Its really strait forward, I advise giving it a try