# How to enumerat or index the properties of a structure

Tags: vb.net, loops, indexing, structure, enumeration

For some time I have been wondering if it is possible to enumerate, or set and index for the properties of an object or structure.

I currently have a set of custom graph generator classes for different reports, but they all accept the same structure as a parameter.

The structures' properties' values get set from a SQL reader that reads columns as they are set up in a table in the database. Now ideally want to loop though these column values sequentially and write them to the properties of the structure.

My Structure is as follows:

```vb
Public Structure MyStructure
    Dim GraphName As String
    Dim GraphValue As Integer
    Dim Red As Integer
    Dim Green As Integer
    Dim Blue As Integer
End Structure
```

Now I want to be able to loop through these properties and assign values to each. E.g.:

```vb
 Dim Struct as MyStructure
 For i as integer = 0 to 4
      Struct.i = "A value retrieved from database"
 Next i
```

The main idea is that i want to avoid using a case statement:

```vb
 Dim Struct as MyStruct
 For i as integer = 0 to 4
      Select Case i
          Case 0
          Struct.GraphName  = "A value retrieved from database"
          Case 1
          Struct.GraphValue = "A value retrieved from database"
          'Etc.
      End Select
 Next i
```

Any insight on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997747/c-sharp-reflection-accessing-the-fields-of-a-struct

Comment: also: [Map a dataset to a custom .NET object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618360/map-a-dataset-to-a-custom-net-object-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "dynamically" access the fields, you would use reflection:

```
Private Structure foo
    Public i As Integer
    Public s As String
End Structure

Private Sub bar()

    Dim f As foo
    Dim fields = GetType(foo).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance)
    For Each fi As FieldInfo In fields
        fi.SetValue(f, GetValueFromDBForName(fi.Name))
    Next

End Sub
```

Be aware that Reflection is NOT fast. "FasterFlect" (via NuGet) or other "fast" replacements might be an alternative. OR you consider to use an ORM (object relational mapping) "out-of-the-box"